# How do I get the list of all terms in a Whoosh index?

Tags: python, whoosh

I'd like to see which terms are used for indexing.  This is mostly for debugging, in case I need to do some additional preprocessing to the documents before sending them to Whoosh.  A list is fine.  Is there a variable that gives me this (perhaps in `whoosh.index`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

- [`whoosh.reading.IndexReader.all_terms()`](https://whoosh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/reading.html#whoosh.reading.IndexReader.all_terms)

  > Yields (fieldname, text) tuples for every term in the index.